# Why dropzone.js/javascript is requesting a different route?

Tags: php, codeigniter, dropzone.js

So, all that I'm trying to do, is to include picture uploading to my proyect. I'm using Dropzone.js but I think I'm doing something wrong in CodeIgniter.

My folder proyect is called `appci` and the idea behind it is watch, create and edit products. For that pourpose, I have a controller called `Products` which is in charge of all this actions. And I'm mentioning this because I think is important.

My update view looks like this (sorry if it's a bit long)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url('assets/dropzone/dropzone.js'); ?>"></script>

<?php echo validation_errors(); ?>

    <br>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h2><?php echo $title; ?></h2>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <?php echo form_open('product/update/'.$news_item["slug"]); ?>
                        <label>ID</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" value=<?php echo "'".$news_item["idnews"]."'"; ?> readonly><br>

                        <label>Title</label>
                        <input type="input" class="form-control" value=<?php echo "'".$news_item["title"]."'"; ?>/><br>

                        <label>Text</label>
                        <textarea class="form-control" rows="3"><?php echo $news_item["text"]; ?></textarea>
                        <br>
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info" name="submit" value="Update product item" />
                        <div class="btn-group">
                            <a href=<?php echo base_url()."product" ?> class="btn btn-danger">
                                <i class="fa fa-cog" aria-hidden="true"></i> Go back to products
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
                <hr>
                <h2>Include pictures</h2>
                <button class="btn btn-success" id="submit-all">Submit all files</button>
                <br><br>
                <form action="./image-upload/post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="dropzone" id="myDropzone" method="POST">
                <div>
                    <h3>Upload Multiple Image By Click On Box</h3>
                </div>
            </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script>
  Dropzone.options.myDropzone = {

  // Prevents Dropzone from uploading dropped files immediately
  autoProcessQueue: false,

  init: function() {
    var submitButton = document.querySelector("#submit-all")
        myDropzone = this; // closure

    submitButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
      myDropzone.processQueue(); // Tell Dropzone to process all queued files.
    });

    // You might want to show the submit button only when 
    // files are dropped here:
    this.on("addedfile", function() {
      // Show submit button here and/or inform user to click it.
    });
  }
};
</script>
```

My route looks like this

```
$route['image-upload/post']['post'] = 'DropzoneImageController/imageUploadPost';
```

As you can see, I have a controller named `DropzoneImageController`, and inside the controller, my `imageUploadPost()` is in charge of uploading the files using the `upload` library included in Codeigniter, just like this:

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class DropzoneImageController extends CI_Controller {

    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('myPost');
    }

    public function imageUploadPost()
    {
        $config['upload_path']   = './uploads/'; 
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png'; 
        $config['max_size']      = 2048;

        $this->load->library('upload', $config);
        $this->upload->do_upload('file');

        print_r('Image Uploaded Successfully.');
        exit;
    }
}
```

And here comes the problem. I have already try this code outside my official proyect and is working. But, when I include this in my proyect, the files are not moving. I went to check with the developer tools in which route is dropzone doing the POST operation and the result is `localhost/appci/product/update/image-upload/post` which is completely wrong. The correct route should be (as specified in the form) `localhost/appci/image-upload/post`. Does anyone has any idea why is this happening?

---

**Extra information**

I added a .htaccess file in the root folder, as follows

```
## START MOD_REWRITE

    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

        RewriteEngine On

        SetEnv HTTP_MOD_REWRITE On

        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

    </IfModule>

## END MOD_REWRITE
```

My complete routes.php file looks like this

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

$route['product/update/(:any)'] = 'product/update/$1';
$route['product/create'] = 'product/create';
$route['product/(:any)'] = 'product/view/$1';


$route['product'] = 'product/index';
$route['(:any)'] = 'product/index';
$route['default_controller'] = 'pages/view';

$route['image-upload/post'] = 'DropzoneImageController/imageUploadPost';
```

And I changed this two options in the config.php file

```
$config['base_url'] = '';


$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
```

Comment: have you tried `$route['image-upload/post'] = 'DropzoneImageController/imageUploadPost';` ?

Comment: @Vickel Well,  just tried that, and it is the same. I think the route is ok, but dropzone/javascript is requesting a differente route and that is why is not matching

Comment: Just a tip your naming the class and file name wrong for CI versions explained here https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/styleguide.html#file-naming and https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html#examples

Comment: but this "dropzone/javascript is requesting a differente route" you have not mentioned in your question, maybe you want to update this?

Comment: and please add those relevant ones for "I added some rules to .htaccess and changed couple of things in config.php"

Comment: @Vickel I didn't mention it in the title, but in the last part I mentioned the wrong and the correct route. I will add the information.

Comment: how do you include/call dropzone.js?

Comment: @Vickel I use `<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url('assets/dropzone/dropzone.js'); ?>"></script>`. I will include the entire code of the view

Comment: if you put this into the file called by the route it should work

Comment: You need to set the base url in config some links may not work if not have it set